# Rewrite so you can access the page from just the folder name

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create a rewrite rule for my .htaccess

I need to access this page: 
mydomain.com/activa/activa.php

by typing: 
mydomain.com/activa

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: just rename activa.php to index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^activa/?$ activa/activa.php
```

should work.

Comment: RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^activa activa/activa.php       When I take out the $ I get the page but without images and css

Comment: Is there a trailing slash after the activa?

Comment: For the missing images and css, check the links, they need to be relative to the URL in the address bar, not relative to the file actually being used.

Comment: Ok. I changed my answer slightly to handle the trailing slash. The answer will now handle domain.com/activa or domain.com/activa/. If you always want the trailing slash, you can remove the question mark after the slash (which makes the slash optional).

Comment: The above rule works for all devices, but for mobile devices I need to resolve to a different page. activa/activa_mobi.php any help will be great.

Comment: Ugh. Mobile sites are a whole other matter. .htaccess by default doesn't have a built in mobile vs desktop detection, which means you would have to build your own, and all you have to work with is the user agent. Often, mobile detection and redirection is best left on the code side rather than in the server config.